# Unlock LUKS device remotely - ipconfig: no devices to configure

Tags: luks, initramfs, ifconfig, dropbear

I am trying to unlock my root encrypted Debian Buster on an acepc T11. I installed dropbear, added

```
DEVICE=enp1s0
IP=:::::enp1s0:dhcp
```

to `/etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf` and executed `update-initramfs -k all -u`. When the initramfs is loaded, I get multple times the error

```
ipconfig: enp1s0: SIOCGIFINDEX: No such device
ipconfig: no devices to configure
```

and a single time the error

```
/scripts/init-premount/dropbear: .: line 275: can't open '/run/net-enp1s0.conf': No such file or directory
```

I can then only proceed by entering the LUKS password at the machine.

A few things I tried:

- The interface `enp1s0` is the one that is shown by `ip a` once the system is fully booted, but seems to be incorrect in the initram?! I tried to omit the interface name so the initram would figure the correct one out by itself, but then I still receive the `ipconfig: no devices to configure` errors and the last error changes to `/scripts/init-premount/dropbear: .: line 275: can't open '/run/net-*.conf': No such file or directory`.
- I also tried the "standard" interface names `eth0` and `eth1` but got the same errors.
- I edited `/boot/cmdline.txt` according to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/374747/ssh-connect-to-host-raspberry-port-22-no-route-to-host) answer, but that didn't help.
- I added `virtio`, `virtio_pci` and `virtio_net` to `/etc/initramfs/modules` as that seemed to help someone with a similar issue (can not find the webpage anymore), but with no success.
- I added `ip=dhcp` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub` as described [in this article](https://hamy.io/post/0009/how-to-install-luks-encrypted-ubuntu-18.04.x-server-and-enable-remote-unlocking). No change at all.
- I created the file `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/cryptroot` with content `target=mmcblk0p3_crypt,source=UUID=49429a5f-f094-485c-8c2e-45f53f81919f` as suggested on [this Q/A site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37024/how-to-open-a-port-early-in-boot-process-to-unlock-luks-via-ssh). (The content of `/etc/crypttab` ist `mmcblk0p3_crypt UUID=49429a5f-f094-485c-8c2e-45f53f81919f none luks,discard,initramfs`, by the way.)

My guess is, that either the network is not up or a driver is missing in that initramfs phase or I have the wrong interface name, but I do not know how to fix the first or how to find out the correct name.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out, that indeed the network driver was missing in the initramfs. The module argument `MODULES=most` in `/etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf` was not sufficient. Thanks to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41817/linux-how-to-find-the-device-driver-used-for-a-device), I found my network driver using `lspci -v` and added the appropriate module to `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules`. After rebuilding the initramfs, I still receive an error about some module that can not be loaded but the network is running nonetheless and I can unlock the LUKS device remotely.